# Excel: When a user on another computer enters the date into a cell, format converts to string

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-dates

I've never had this error before and I can't find anything about it on google.

Basically, I have a workbook with an "instructions" page that has some macro buttons and a cell to enter a specific date. This cell is date-type, not string-type.

I have no issues on my computer entering the date. I normally enter it as ex. "20/09/01 12:00 am" and it's displayed in the desired format of "20/09/01 0:00". I have calculation options set as automatic to do that so the user can enter it however the want.

However, I've had two users test this workbook on their computers, and when they enter the date into that cell, even in the exact same way I do, once they hit enter- it changes to a string format. I've made sure that calculation options are the same as well.

I know Excel can be finicky with some formulas in vba like datevalue across computers because of regional setting but this is just entering the date in a cell. I've done it the exact same way on their computer as I do it on mine, but it onlny stays as a date on my computer after hitting enter.

Can someone please assist?

Thank you

Comment: Have them check their local settings.  My guess is that their local settings are different and as such Excel does not recognize it as a date.

Comment: drop the time part, and change the formatting of the cell to long date. Enter the date 20/09/01 in the cell.  See if the date displayed on your computer and on their computer is the same.  That is a strong indicator of regional settings in windows being different between the machines